# What purpose does pgadmin in PostgreSQL serve?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am confused with pgadmin. What is the main purpose of it in Postgres server?

Comment: It's one of [many](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients) SQL clients

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple and short.

The pgadmin in PostgreSQL is a data administration tool. It serves the purpose of retrieving, developing, testing, and maintaining databases.

Answer (score 0):

From their website:

> pgAdmin is the most popular and feature rich Open Source
> administration and development platform for PostgreSQL

From the Navicat website, another SQL client:

> Navicat for PostgreSQL is an easy-to-use graphical tool for PostgreSQL
> database development. From writing simple SQL queries to developing
> complex databases, Navicat for PostgreSQL is designed to accommodate a
> wide range of users, from PostgreSQL beginners to seasoned developers.

And DataGrip:

> Meet DataGrip, our new database IDE that is tailored to suit the
> specific needs of professional SQL developers.